# Can't import braces library

Tags: python, django, import, braces

I use braces for my project. But when I import it to my views.py, it shows yellow error that there is no such a library. But it exists on libraries of the project. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your editor is not using python version of your virtual environment. You don't have to worry about this.